# Why need to be a friend to access protected members?

Tags: c++, friend, protected

When I'm in `Sub::f()` and try to access the protected members of another sub-class to which the `Base* b` pointer points to, it won't compile until `Sub` is a friend of Base. Why do I need to do this?

```
class Base{
//friend class Sub;
protected:
    int i;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Sub : public Base{
    Base* b;
public:
    Sub(Base* ba) : b(ba){}
    void f(){
        b->f();
        cout << b->i << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Because that's what `friend` is.

Comment: because you can only lets your friends touch your private parts.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/friends.html

Comment: But `Sub` inherits everything from `Base`. Don't derived classes have access to protected members of their base-class?

Comment: if you are having a specific issue try posting a more complete and self contained example.

Comment: @Daniel _'But Sub inherits everything from Base.'_ So why do you have an extra member for `Base`??

Comment: Ok I guess `Sub` has to be a friend because `Base* b` has another object and it's unimportant whether the access happens in a sub-class or elsewhere -> the accessing object/function has to be a friend.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have something like a composite-pattern-structure (one sub-class can have another sub-class or is a endpoint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*protected* members are accessible in own class and in derived class but not outside of the class so if you want to do it, use 'friend'. And because of this feature provided by CPP,CPP is not 'fully or complete' object oriented programming language (loophole) as we can access private members too with friend's help.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` can be accessed only in *hierarchy*, but if you want exception, making friend is the way.

Friend class can access both `private` and `protected` members of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`b->f()` and `b->i` are not accessing `f` and `b` of his own base, but of somebody else base (the one pointed by `b`)

```
sub    base
|____b_|___i___|
     |
     |_
       |
       V
sub    base
|____b_|___i___|
```

Comment: Thx;) Thats a nice picture.